# Spec tests looking for table names as `module_name_table_name`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have setup a Rails-api app where there is a user outside of the `V1` namespace. `Player` represents the user to the API. Previously, when all models were within the module `V1`, all was well.  Now when I run the tests I get:

```
    V1::PlayersController GET players returns all players
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create :player, user_id: 1
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'v1_players'
```

Is this a common mistake?  The only thing I can think of is that I made a mistake in my migrations.  They are standard and make no mention of v1, so I can't imagine why ActiveRecord is expecting that name.

Here's the spec, in case that helps:

```
describe V1::PlayersController, :type => :controller do 

    describe "GET players" do
        it "returns all players" do 
            FactoryGirl.create :player, user_id: 1
            FactoryGirl.create :player, user_id: 2

            get :index, :format => :json

            expect(response.status).to eq 200

            body = JSON.parse(response.body)
            player_user_ids = body.map { |m| m["user_id"] }

            expect(player_user_ids).to match_array(["1",
                                               "2"])
        end
    end
end
```

And the `Player` Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player, class: V1::Player do
    user_id 5
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this as expected behavior according to the ActiveRecord Documentation.  I have run a migration on the tables to comply.  I also learned that you can run a rails generator with the argument module_name::class_name rather than just the class name.